# unable to load sample file into hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I tried to install 2.2.0 pseudo mode,while I try to run `copyfromlocal` to copy a sample data

i used **/input** in destination path now, like-**bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/prassanna/Desktop/input /input**

i think its worked now and i verified the file using below,
**bin/hadoop fs -ls /input**
14/03/12 09:31:57 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... 
using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 
1 items
**-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup         64** 
and i also checked in uI of datanode,
but its showing used % is '0' only,but it has to show some kb's(64) of the file right?Please tell is  the input file copied to hdfs properly ?**
and tell me where the file is physically stored in local machine exactly?Please help to solve this confusion.Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your OS and how you installed Hadoop?

Comment: what command u r running? and what where is the file placed?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 12.04 and i am running                 root@prassanna-Studio-1558:/usr/local/hadoop# bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/prassanna/Desktop/input input here i have used the sample text file named input as local file  in desktop.

Comment: what does this show # ls -ltr /home/prassanna/Desktop....wondering if you are missing any extension...or you can try this..if thats verified try this too...#bin/hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/prassanna/Desktop/input /input

Comment: Hi Thanks, i put /input in destination,its worked i think, i posted my doubts ,please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your source path is missing then you have to check for the existence of file on your local machine.

But if destination folder is not missing then first try to check then existence of that folder on HDFS. 
For that you can open Web UI of hadoop HDFS by *:50070* and then *Browse the file system*

Alternative to this you can check files through Command

```
 hadoop fs -ls /<path of HDFS directory >
```

If this works then put file with following command

```
  hadoop fs -put <local file path>  <path of HDFS directory>
```

If any of  these doesn't work then your hadoop is missing some important configuration

If your Web UI is opening but command is not running then try like this

```
 hadoop fs -ls hdfs://<hadoop Master ip>/<path of HDFS directory >
```

If this works run put command as below

```
 hadoop fs -put <local file path> hdfs://<hadoop Master ip>/<path of HDFS directory >
```